# Python MySQL Regex String Extra Backlashes Are Added

Tags: python, mysql, regex, web-scraping

I've just started using Python and MySQL together and I've noticed that when I store a RegEx string such as `\r\n` or `\"` when I retrieve it  from the database using Python I get `\\r\\n` or `\\"`. As you can imagine the regular expression no longer works when this happens and messes up my scraper. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: the slashes `\\` are escaped

Comment: is there a way I can get Python to read a \n as an actual new line and not text to prevent it from escaping?

Comment: how are you seeing  `\\r\\n`?

Comment: From my debugger. Now I do realize this is not the literal interpretation, however I need `\r\n` to be an actual newline for my regular expression to work. It seems that if I have `\r\n` represented as text and not as a new line then my regular expression fails.

Comment: have you tried using `r`?

Comment: That does not work, since Python takes it as a literal r.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59463/discussion-between-uriel-katz-and-padraic-cunningham).

Comment: Try using `str.decode('string_escape')`

Comment: That works however it prevents me from being able to repeat a line break with `*?`, or group line breaks with non-capturing groups.

Comment: I'm thinking the easiest way to do this would be to remove all line breaks from the original text in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Padraic already mentioned that the character gets escaped when inserting into your database. This due to the character `\` being unsafe as a raw character in a string.

You are advised against storing such characters in the database. Either encrypt the data to prevent escaping or use the regex in code.

In addition, `\r` stands for carriage return, this is the mechanism in editors that tells the carret to return to the first character on the `current line` it is on.

If you just want to match newline, use `\n`. Infact, i've even encountered some situations where `\r\n` failed to properly match as where `\n` didn't.\

Example for regex newline: http://regex101.com/r/vB4bU0/1

I hope this helps you further.